# Including sections of source code as a listing, while being robust to source code edits

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

Is there a way to input particular sections of source code using `\lstinputlisting` (from the `listings` package) in a flexible way?  It's possible to use the `firstline` and `lastline` options to input particular line ranges, but this isn't robust to changes to the source file.

For example, suppose that the input source file is:

```
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

int cube(int x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
```

In my LaTeX document, I can include the `cube` procedure using the command `\lstinputlisting[firstline=5,lastline=7]{source.c}`.

But suppose I later decide to rewrite the `cube` procedure.  The input source file becomes:

```
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

int cube(int x) {
  int x2;
  x2 = square(x);
  return x * x2;
}
```

Now my LaTeX document will not show the final two lines of `cube` because the listing uses only lines 5-7.  I could manually update the line range, but this is tedious and error-prone.

Is there a way to mark sections of source code with some kind of label so that the listing will be robust to these sorts of changes?  For instance, perhaps the input source file would be something like

```
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

/**\beginlabel{lst:cube} **/
int cube(int x) {
  int x2;
  x2 = square(x);
  return x * x2;
}
/**\endlabel{lst:cube} **/
```

so that I could use something like `\lstinputlisting[lines=lst:cube]{source.c}` to include the section that I want and remain robust to changes.

I am open to using other packages for source code listings (e.g., `minted`) if helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short guide

1. Set the prefixes and suffixes for your markers. Replace the space with `\` (backslash plus space)
2. Decide if the marker lines should be part of the output or not.
3. Include the code and use the text between the prefixes and sufixes as “line numbers” for the `linerange` option.

```
% create the test file for this example
\begin{filecontents}{external.c}
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

@@@START@@@
int cube(int x) {
  int x2;
  x2 = square(x);
  return x * x2;
}
@@@STOP@@@

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    rangeprefix=@@@,% [1]
    rangesuffix=@@@,
    includerangemarker=false,% [2]
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange=START-STOP]{external.c}%[3]
\end{document}
```

For more details see section “5.7 Arbitrary linerange markers” in the manual …

Answer (score 12):

The `listings` package provides an experimental feature for *arbritrary linerange markers* (see §5.7 of the [listings manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)).

```
// example.c
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

/* BEGIN */
int cube(int x) {
  int x2;
  x2 = square(x);
  return x * x2;
}
/* END */
```

MWE to demonstrate the `linerange` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{rangeprefix=\/\*\ ,rangesuffix=\ \* \/}

\begin{document}
Example.c

   \lstinputlisting[language=C, linerange=BEGIN-END]{example.c}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can use the `includerangemarker=false` option to prevent that the line range markers (`/* BEGIN */` and `/* END */`) itself become part of the output.